# "Date de baja aquí" para cancelar una suscripción: significado de "date"

Tags: verbos, conjugación

Recibí un correo electrónico spam en español que no me gustó, y busqué la opción para cancelar la suscripción. La encontré, pero usaba una estructura un poco rara para mí. Decía esto:

> ¿Ya no te hace falta esta información? **Date** de baja aquí

Parece que "Date de baja" usa el imperativo de **datar**. ¿Es correcto eso? ¿O es otra palabra? Si es "datar", ¿por qué usa esta palabra, y no "cancelar la suscripción" o "dejarse de baja"?

Comment: He hecho algunas correcciones en la pregunta. En particular, las comillas en español se escriben antes del punto, a diferencia de lo que suele hacerse en inglés.

Comment: ¡Gracias por avisarme @OnlyThenDidIReckonMyCurse!

Comment: He hecho unas pequeñas correcciones adicionales para hacer tu texto más idiomático. He eliminado "yo" en "yo busqué". Date cuenta que no lo has incluido en el resto de tu texto, lo cual es correcto. No has puesto "Yo recibí un correo ... Yo la encontré ..." etc. Supongo que ya lo sabes pero el sujeto, la forma personal ya va implicito en la forma verbal. Lo añadimos únicamente para hacer enfatizar como el verbo auxiliar "do" se añade en una frase afirmativa en inglés.

Comment: Por otro lado, he eliminado la preposición "por" en "busqué por la opción". "La opción" es el objeto directo y no requiere de preposición en español. Si quisieras indicar el lugar donde has buscado la opción, sí llevaría "por": "Busqué la opción por la web", por ejemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es "datar". "Datar" no tiene ese significado, y en todo caso su imperativo sería "data [tú]", "date [usted]", "datemos [nosotros]", "datad [vosotros]", "daten [ustedes]". Teniendo en cuenta que en la primera frase se refieren al destinatario en segunda persona informal ("¿Ya no **te** hace falta...?") en lugar de segunda persona formal (sería "¿Ya no **le** hace falta...?"), la forma que se usaría no sería "date [usted]" sino "data [tú]".

Es el imperativo de "darse" (verbo pronominal: "dar" + "se"). El imperativo de "dar" es "da [tú]", "dé [usted]", "demos [nosotros]", "dad [vosotros]", "den [ustedes]", con lo que el de "darse" es "date [tú]", "dese [usted]", "démonos [nosotros]", "daos [vosotros]", "dense [ustedes]". "Dar" tiene muchos significados (53 cuenta el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/dar?m=form)), y uno que encajaría en esta situación sería:

> 8. tr. Suponer, declarar, considerar. Lo doy POR visto, POR inocente. U. t. c. prnl. Se dio POR perdido, POR muerto.

En cualquier caso, "darse de alta" es una expresión idiomática habitual que significa "inscribirse":

> 2. tr. Apuntar el nombre de una persona entre los de otras para un objeto determinado. U. t. c. prnl.

Y "darse de baja" es otra expresión igual de habitual que significa lo contrario, cancelar una inscripción (podríamos decir que equivale a "borrarse", aunque los significados de "borrarse" son más generales).

En cuanto a "cancelar la suscripción", sería correcto, pero muy formal. "Dejarse de baja" no es correcto, porque "darse de baja" es una expresión idiomática que no admite la sustitución de sus componentes por términos distintos. Sí sería correcto, aunque largo, "dejar de recibir correos de esta lista", por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

No, `date` no viene de datar sino de `darse` 
https://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/dar_de_baja.php

Esta es la maravilla de los verbos irregulares, te crees que viene de uno y viene de otro totalmente distinto

Comment: "Datar" es regular. "Dar" es irregular, pero la forma "date" es perfectamente regular: raíz ("d", el infinitivo sin el "-ar") más desinencia regular de 2ª persona informal ("-a", como en el verbo modelo "amar": "ama [tú]") más pronombre enclítico ("te").

Comment: los irregulares, como bien dices, no tienen que ser irregulares siempre, solo en algunas formas, por eso, es común pensar que tiene que venir de otro verbo (datar) cuando viene de darse, porque esperas que sea irregular siempre. También sucede al contrario sobre todo en niños cuando aprenden a hablar, en cuanto van al cole, tienden a 'regularizar' los irregulares

Comment: Esas expresiones son de más uso en España